# Access jQueryUI Dialog buttons upon creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

How do I access jQueryUI Dialog buttons upon creation and get their size?  As a workaround, I could do so when it is opened.

http://jsfiddle.net/1ueho4tq/

```
var $button1;
var dialog = $('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    create: function (event, ui) {
        var $button1 = $('#button1');
        console.log("$button1 create", $button1, $button1.outerHeight(), $button1.position().top);
    },
    open: function (event, ui) {
        if (!$button1) {
            $button1 = $('#button1');
            console.log("$button1 open", $button1, $button1.outerHeight(), $button1.position().top);
        }
    },
    buttons: [{
        id: 'button1',
        text: 'Upload',
        click: function () {
            console.log('button1');
        }
    }, {
        id: 'button2',
        text: 'Save',
        click: function () {
            console.log('button2');
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Cancel',
        click: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }]
});
$('#open').click(function () {
    dialog.dialog('open');
});

<div id="dialog"></div>
<button id="open">Open</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the jQuery UI dialog buttons using [`buttons`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons) option getter.

Code:

```
var buttons = $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'buttons');
```

But if you need to check their dimensions you need to use the array after the dialog is opened.

Code:

```
open: function (event, ui) {
    $.each(buttons, function (i, e) {
        console.log($('#'+e.id).outerHeight())
    });
},
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f4m6z9hc/

Comment: Thanks Irvin.  So they don't really exist until the dialog is opened?

Comment: @user1032531 no if you check the DOM, they are already in it, it depends on what you want to do

Comment: Then why can't I get the size and position of them if they are already in the DOM?